# How to fix Property "$_" was accessed during ... error?

Tags: vue.js

I try to add custom template to my Laravel 8 / vuejs3 / inertia-vue3  app, but looking at code of vuejs templates
I see a lot of faker code, like

```
<div
    v-for="(faker, fakerKey) in $_.take($f(), 4)"
    :key="fakerKey"
    class="intro-y"
>
    <div class="box px-4 py-4 mb-3 flex items-center zoom-in">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

I found file  resources/app/utils/faker.js with content :

```
const fakers = {
  fakeUsers() {
    const users = [
      { name: 'Johnny Depp', gender: 'male' },
      ...
      
  fakeProducts() {
    const products = [
      { name: 'Dell XPS 13', category: 'PC & Laptop' },
      ...
```

In my vue file I imported utils :

```
  import faker from '@/utils/faker'

  export default defineComponent({
      components: {
          ...
          faker,
      },
```

But in browser's console I see error :

```
app.js:10219 [Vue warn]: Property "$_" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.
```

Did I miss some declarations ?

In package.json :

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@inertiajs/inertia": "^0.10.0",
    "@inertiajs/inertia-vue3": "^0.5.1",
    "@inertiajs/progress": "^0.2.6",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.4.0",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.5",
     "postcss": "8.3.1",
    "postcss-import": "^12.0.1",
    "postcss-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "sass": "^1.46.0",
    "sass-loader": "^12.4.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.2.19",
    "vue": "^3.0.5",
    "vue-loader": "^16.1.2"
    ...
},
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `faker` is not a component, it doesn't make sense to use it as such. Where does this code originate from and why do you expect it to work? The error means that there is no $_ property. $_.take looks like lodash and you possibly can expose it with something like vue-lodash, but there are not enough details to confirm this.

Comment: Tha is actually https://themeforest.net/item/midone-vuejs-admin-dashboard-template/28123408 template
and its demo pages work ok
In /package.json of the app(I coped all packes to my project) I see
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",

But I did not find any vue-lodash in the project. Please hints how to make this project working ?

Comment: There should be `Vue.prototype.$_ = _`, where `_` is Lodash. You can search original project for `$_`, it should have been somewhere